# How to switch between different version of APA-style citations?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

From the file [biblatex-apa-test.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) that comes along with the [biblatex-apa package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa.pdf), we could visually distinguish use cases of different APA's version (APA 8, 9, 10, ...).

I feel comfortable using biblatex and the apa style, nevertheless, I would like to know how to switch between different versions of APA. For instance, I am blocked when I want to use APA 7, considering that the following code (on page 3 of the documentation) typeset citations using a version that seems to be greater than 7.x.

```latex
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
```

Sometimes, I am forced to use apa6 for style which is close to the APA 7 guidelines.

```latex
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: The numbers 8, 9 and 10 in the linked document refer to chapter numbers of the APA manual (7th edition), so you will get 7th-ed. APA style from `style=apa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no APA edition 8, 9 or 10. The most recent edition of the ["Publication Manual Of The American Psychological Association"](https://apastyle.apa.org/products/publication-manual-7th-edition-spiral) is the 7th from 2019.

The numbers refer to the examples given in the corresponding chapters, i.e.

> (APA 8.6)
>   Secondary sources. The example in APA 7th is inconsistent with other examples of similar format which use a semi-colon:
>
> `\parencites{8.6a}[as cited in][]{8.6b}`
>
> (Rabbitt, 1982; as cited in Lyon et al., 2014)

means that the example is from chapter eight, section six of APA 7th edition.

Comment: It is ok that there is no APA 8, 9, 10. Then, can you point me on the command responsible for triggering such differences between those citations? For instance, I want a colon instead of a comma between The Publisher Name and The Location.